# make or say with 'prayer'

Tags: word-usage

For words that we say to God asking for help I've found that two phrases are used.

1. make prayer
2. say prayer

I've usually seen that natives don't much use the first one. Is there any error in this or is it unusual? Although to me second is more natural and I prefer it but still I've got this perplexity in my mind that "What wrong is there in the first one?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally never heard the expression "*make* prayer" (native BrEng speaker). If you have a credible example then perhaps it is used in some parts of the world or maybe it is archaic.

There are a few other ways to express what you want. Remember that the verb is *to pray* and the noun, or name for the completed set of words is *a prayer*.

- Say *a* prayer
  eg "He said a prayer".
- Pray
  eg "I will pray for you".
- to be *in prayer*
  eg "He knelt down in prayer",
  or "her lips were moving in silent prayer".

Comment: "Make prayers" certainly is used, but it seems rare.  There is a book "Make Prayers to the Raven", Richard Nelson, 1983.  Also OED records old usage (c1475) "make my preyrys to þe Trenyte".  Online you will see it occasionally, possibly from non-native speakers.